# using data outside while-loop

Tags: php, while-loop, implode

I am using this code which calls the `period_id :`

```
$cart = $this->GetUserCart();
$dataset = array();
while ($data = $cart->fetch_array()) {  
    $dataset[] = $data['period_id'];
}
```

so I need to implode the result so they can be separated by comma

```
$p = implode(",",$dataset);
```

So in the usercart function will call for example, 3 distinct `period_id`

so I need to finish like this :

```
$p='2,5,3';
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Your query is correct.

Comment: yes i need to save the output data into variable separated by comas

Comment: if i print the dataset it shows Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 1 )  how do i separate this?

Comment: You've just do it. Using `implode` function.

Comment: What are you getting and what do you want to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct. Maybe you just have to echo it.

```
$dataset = array();
while ($data = $cart->fetch_array()) {  
    $dataset[] = $data['period_id'];
}

$p = implode(',', $dataset);
echo $p; //you just need to echo it
```

Comment: What is the difference from the question? Just to add an `echo`? Is it possible that somebody knows little about `php` but not knows how to `echo` output!!!

Comment: lol. I've nothing to say as this answer is accepted. Sorry @aldrin27 for my previous comment.

Comment: @Chayan it's okay bro :)

Answer (score 0):

I think if

```
        $p = implode(",",$dataset);
```

if            `$dataset = array("1", "5", "3");`

when you     `echo $p ; //output will be 1,5,3`

put if you add this :

```
       $p = "'".implode(",",$dataset)."'";
       echo $p ; //output will be '1,5,3'
```

and that is what you need if i understand you so

```
       $p = '1,5,3';
```

Comment: lol. Why would he concatenate the imploded data? If the actual data is correct?

Comment: ya , but sometimes you need output looks like groups and may use more than one implode results for example ,'1,2,3','1,4,7'  say we have two array then we need out put to be like that , echo "'".implode(",",$dataset)."'" ; echo ","; echo "'".implode(",",$dataset2)."'" ; and so on